# web3j - Unable to call a function that returns tuple[]

Tags: solidity, web3j

I am relatively new to interacting with smart contracts in java and I am facing a problem while trying to retrieve a tuple[] returned by the smart contract function. Here is the ABI definition of the function I want to call:

```
{
  "inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],
  "name":"claimableRewards",
  "outputs":
    [{"components":
      [
        {"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},
        {"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}
      ],
      "internalType":"struct MultiFeeDistribution.RewardData[]",
      "name":"rewards",
      "type":"tuple[]"
    }],
  "stateMutability":"view",
  "type":"function"
}
```

Here is the link to the smart contract code:
https://polygonscan.com/address/0x920f22e1e5da04504b765f8110ab96a20e6408bd#code

And here is the java code that I wrote to call the function (I have removed the errors checking to make the code easier to read) :

```
        List<Type> claimableRewardsParams = Arrays.<Type>asList(new Address(credentials.getAddress()));
        List<TypeReference<?>> claimableRewardsReturnTypes = Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<DynamicArray<DynamicStruct>>() {});

        final Function claimableRewardsFunction = new Function(
                "claimableRewards",
                claimableRewardsParams,
                claimableRewardsReturnTypes);

        String claimableRewardsEncodedFunction = FunctionEncoder
                .encode(claimableRewardsFunction);          

        EthCall claimableRewardsResponse = web3.ethCall(
                Transaction.createEthCallTransaction(walletAddress, adamantRewardsContractAddress, claimableRewardsEncodedFunction),
                DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST)
                .sendAsync().get();

        List<Type> claimableRewardsSomeTypes = FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(
                claimableRewardsResponse.getValue(), claimableRewardsFunction.getOutputParameters());
```

When I run the program I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: TypeReferenced struct must contain a constructor with types that extend Type
```

I have tried several other definitions for claimableRewardsReturnTypes but I can't get it to work. Can someone please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with `web3j` internal types is not the best starting point.

What you can do is generate the `Java` contract wrappers for your `ABI`. The wrappers are Java classes that abstract the internal `Web3j` logic and provide you with functions you can use to interact with your contract using native Java types.

You can do that, for example, using the [web3j-cli](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-cli) and use the following:

```
$ web3j generate solidity -a <abi_file> -o <output_dir> -p <package_name>
```

Another easier way is to use the [web3j-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-gradle-plugin) or [web3j-maven-plugin](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-gradle-plugin) to generate the wrappers from your projects via the provided `generateContractWrappers` and use the wrappers from there.

Comment: I've created java wrapper class but when i call a function it returns a transaction receipt instead of function value.

Comment: That is a current limitation of the Web3J library. If the function changes state and at the same time returns a value. The value cannot be retrieved currently and only the transaction receipt will be returned.
There has been some work on supporting this, but I don't think it is ready.